# Active Page for CSS using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a menu with an active page element for CSS using PHP and MySQL.

This **example** PHP/HTML hybrid works, and is what I'm trying to mimic.

```
<nav><ul>
<li<?php if ($thisPage == "1") echo " class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="pg1.php">page 1</a></li>
<li<?php if ($thisPage == "2") echo " class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="pg2.php">page 2</a></li>
<li<?php if ($thisPage == "3") echo " class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="pg3.php">page 3</a></li>
</nav></ul>
```

I want to blend this statement to set the active class:

```
<?php if ($thisPage == $menuID) echo " class=\"active\""; ?>
```

Into this unordered list statement

```
<?php 
echo "\n<nav>\n";
echo "<ul>\n";
        while($row_rsMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMenu)) 
{   
echo "<li>" .  "<a href=\"" . $row_rsMenu['menuURL'] . "\">" . $row_rsMenu['menuName'] . "</a></li>\n"; 
}   
echo "</ul>\n";
echo "</nav>\n";
?>
```

This is where I am but I can't seem to get the syntax to work correctly.

```
echo "<li" .  "if(" . $thisPage==$menuID . ")".  echo ' class=\"active\"';" . ">" .  "<a href=\"" . $row_rsMenu['menuURL'] . "\">" . $row_rsMenu['menuName'] . "</a></li>\n";
```

If someone could help me to understand where this went wrong I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your if statement encapsulated in quotes. That means that PHP won't interpret it. Instead, it will print it out along with your HTML.

Something along the lines of this will work better:

```
    echo "\n<nav>\n";
    echo "<ul>\n";
    while($row_rsMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMenu)) 
    {  
        $active = ""; //not active by default
        if($thisPage==$menuID){
            $active = ' class="active" ';
        }
        echo "<li>" .  "<a href=\"" . $row_rsMenu['menuURL'] . "\"".$active.">" . $row_rsMenu['menuName'] . "</a></li>\n"; 
    }   
    echo "</ul>\n";
    echo "</nav>\n";
```

By the way, where are you getting $menuID from?

Comment: Works Great! I have a table in the database for building the menu. it is just to verify that the page you see is active...Thanks again!

Comment: actually the only tweak was to move the $active var to the <li> tag but the code works great.

Comment: totally slipped my brain...$menuID.. modified to $row_rsMenu['menuID']

Answer (score 0):

Your error is wrapping the `if` block within quotes, among a few other issues with quotes.

Try this instead:

```
echo '<li',  (($thisPage==$menuId) ? ' class="active"' : ''), '>', '<a href="', $row_rsMenu['menuURL'], '">', $row_rsMenu['menuName'], '</a></li>';
```

This uses a [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) to shorten things up a bit, in addition to fixing your syntax error.